# Odd checkbox behavior, in different browsers

Tags: html, forms, checkbox, cross-browser

On my contact page: http://onthemouse.com/contact-us/
I have a set of checkboxes, they appear perfect in firefox, show a little weird behavior(box enlarges, turns grey on click, check mark becomes smaller, returns to normal on blur or when you click somewhere else), doesnt show up at all in Chrome and Safari OS X(according to browserlabs). Firefox OS X seem to just show dots (again according to browserlabs). These are just simple checkboxes and the only thing peculiar is the id `Field[]` it has the brackets because it's used to create and array when the form is sent.

Checkbox Code:

```
 <div style="display:inline;">
    <span>
      <label class="choice" for="Field1" style="display:inline;margin-left:0px;margin-right:5px;">
        <input id="Field1" name="Field[]" type="checkbox" class="field checkbox" value="Web Design" style="width:0px;">Web Design    
 </label>
    </span>
    <span>
      <label class="choice" for="Field2" style="display:inline;margin-left:0px;margin-right:5px;">
        <input id="Field2" name="Field[]" type="checkbox" class="field checkbox" value="Graphic Design" style="width:0px;">Graphic Design
</label>
    </span>
</div>
```

Form Code:
http://pastebin.com/E3ExGPvv

Comment: `width:0` really? Inline CSS all the way and pasted in pastebin and not jsfiddle, dabbblet or equivalent? Please

Comment: inline css was only temporary. And that fixed it, i'm not sure why i put it there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

http://tinypic.com/r/11iiude/6

You did wrong id naming for second line of check boxes.
Syntax error. Period.